# Simple Background Music for website

Tags: html, button, background-music

I have been designing a website recently and I had the idea to try implementing some background music.

I went about this by simply having the music play through a video looper

```
    <embed name="Example Song Here"
src="http://www.infinitelooper.com/?v=GGtcJCzB9cU&p=n"
loop="True"
hidden="true"
autostart="true">
</embed
```

That works perfectly, the problem comes that users will probably want to stop the music, so I added a "Stop Music" button

```
FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="WebsiteURL">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Stop Music">
</FORM>
```

Adds the button fine, but as you can see it doesn't do anything but redirect back to the site, I've been looking for that extra line I need to make the button stop the music above.

Yes, I'm a total novice.

Comment: It's 2015, use `<audio />` :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: It's 2015, please don't use any background music on websites at all. At least not without the permission of the user. If the user needs to activate the music himself first, it's fine, but anything else will most probably considered quite annoying.

Comment: It's not.. a website for public.. I'm simply learning what you can do with HTML.

Comment: @Cinn if it's a learning exercise there's no reason to not use current features. What you've tried is a bit outdated and what you'd learn wouldn't be as beneficial as learning modern standards.

Comment: @pawel Forgive me for not being as up to date as everyone else.

Comment: @Cinn no problem, you're learning and that's why you're here, and we are here to help. I just don't want you to learn something I consider obsolete when I know of better approach which will benefit you in the future, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

This code uses Html5. if you can use html5 this works fine.

```html
<audio id="myAudio"
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4"
         type='audio/mp4'>
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga"
         type='audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis'>
 Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
<button type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause()">Play/Pause</button>
<script>
function aud_play_pause() {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  if (myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: recommended approach for using youtube is:<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>

Comment: Okay, that's interesting, can I ask how I could have the music playing  but in the background but also utilize that nice play/pause button you have?

Comment: @Cinn you can use Youtube API to create a player with your own controls:  http://jsfiddle.net/jfx5sm55/

Comment: @pawel I don't think I'm at that level of proficiency to know what to do with this.
the stuff Adi made works just fine but I don't know how to change the .mp4 with music of my choosing while still having the pause/play button work.

Answer (score 0):

The [`embed` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-embed-element) as such is conforming in the current HTML specification (HTML5), but it isn’t what it used to be. The old, nonstandard `embed` element had various attributes that controlled the presentation, but they are not included in the specification and support to them varies greatly and is diminishing. Besides, your example does not actually embed sound directly. Instead, it embeds an HTML element, which has embedded sound its own way. Normally you cannot control what happens on a page that you embed from another server.

There is no HTML way to control playing in an `embed` element, since it is expected to be implemented with a plugin. Note that modern browsers might lack any plugins for the purpose by default or might have such plugins disabled. So `embed` really isn’t what it used to be.

Others have suggested, for good reasons, that you don’t use background sound and that if you use, implement it with the `audio` element. (You could have an `embed` element *inside* the `audio` element, as fallback content for browsers that do not recognize `audio` markup at all.) However, `audio` only applies to *direct* embedding of sound, as opposite to embedding a page that has background sound.

In your case, you can create your own stop button using JavaScript. You can make a click on the button to simply remove the `embed` element. Of course, it would then simply terminate the sound. Removing an element is a bit indirect in JavaScript: you tell its parent to kick that child out.

```
<embed id=bgs name="Example Song Here" controls=stopbutton
src="http://www.infinitelooper.com/?v=GGtcJCzB9cU&p=n">
</embed>
<button onclick=
"var bgs = document.getElementById('bgs'); bgs.parentNode.removeChild(bgs);
this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">
Stop background sound</button>
```

Comment: That is very nice, however, the embed has literally embedded the infinitelooper site/logo screenshot: http://gyazo.com/409a8ae7dfbc059e4753e05a646a42e6

Is there a way we can hide that but keep the button visible?

If there's a better method for stop/start using an mp3, mp4 etc file somewhere would that be easier?